# Error when trying to convert .pb file to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to convert the link template, to .tflite, using this code, but it always gives an error.
Model link: https://tfhub.dev/google/openimages_v4/ssd/mobilenet_v2/1

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

saved_model_dir = 'path of file'
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
tflite_model = converter.convert()

with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

Error Message:

```
SavedModel file does not exist at: openimages_v3_ssd_mobilenet_v2_1/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}
```

Answer (score 0):

`saved_model_dir` should point to the SavedModel [directory](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#the_savedmodel_format_on_disk) containing the assets, variables & .pb graph data. I think you are providing one of the files' path.

Comment: When I download the model from the link, the following files come saved_model.pb and tfhub_module.pb and two folders called variables and assets, but the folders are empty.

Comment: Even then, you need to point to the folder that contains the .pb file, not the file itself :-)